# How I can insert a column-file in a hash with a key as an array?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, comparison

I have the next file:

```
-38     miRNA18 8       44      dvex109349      6618    6580
35      miRNA5  21      57      dvex110330      1917    1952
26      miRNA2  27      54      dvex110362      1092    1118
-30     miRNA43 60      90      dvex110558      464     434
30      miRNA2  31      63      dvex111097      1359    1389
-30     miRNA31 43      73      dvex111146      4337    4307
-29     miRNA32 32      63      dvex111322      5680    5651
35      miRNA43 60      95      dvex111435      5612    5647
-26     miRNA43 55      80      dvex111770      723     697
-39     miRNA43 21      58      dvex112127      4928    4889
-32     miRNA2  70      102     dvex112254      1554    1522
33      miRNA17 56      89      dvex113799      2985    3018
38      miRNA17 26      64      dvex113799      2985    3023
40      miRNA17 30      70      dvex113799      2985    3025
```

I need to insert it into a hash, but with these parameters: the column 5 (dvex####) must be the key, and the others will be the values to this key. The idea, is group it by equal keys, and obtain the lower value of the column 6 and the maximun value of the column 7. 
I think that is convenient create a hash with keys as an array, then organize it with that parameters.

The output should be:

```
-38     miRNA18 8       44      dvex109349      6618    6618
35      miRNA5  21      57      dvex110330      1917    1952
-38     miRNA18 8       44      dvex109349      6618    6580
35      miRNA5  21      57      dvex110330      1917    1952
26      miRNA2  27      54      dvex110362      1092    1118
-30     miRNA43 60      90      dvex110558      464     434
30      miRNA2  31      63      dvex111097      1359    1389
-30     miRNA31 43      73      dvex111146      4337    4307
-29     miRNA32 32      63      dvex111322      5680    5651
35      miRNA43 60      95      dvex111435      5612    5647
-26     miRNA43 55      80      dvex111770      723     697
-39     miRNA43 21      58      dvex112127      4928    4889
-32     miRNA2  70      102     dvex112254      1554    1522
33      miRNA17 26      70      dvex113799      2985    3025 #note this result is a group.
```

I'm very interesting because the solution is based in a file with different columns...

Comment: What was wrong with the answers you got here? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015881/hash-key-as-array-to-obtain-the-minimum-and-maximum-numbers-if-a-columns-values]

Answer (score 0):

using a regex or split extract columns 6 (and maybe 6,7) to a scalar.

store the line into a nested hash.

```
$data1{$v5}{$v6}=$_;
$data2{$v5}{$v7}=$_;
```

List::Util will help with max/min

```
use List::Util qw[min max];
foreach $v5 (sort keys %data) {
     $val6=min(keys $data1{$v5});
     $val7=max(keys $data2{$v5});
 now generate your output line as you desire.
}
```